# How to get a list/array of all content entities?

Tags: 8, entities

I need a list of all content entities, to query them all and check if they have a specific field.

Couldn't find this in the API doku.

Comment: Check the existence of field or empty value of field?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityType;

$content_entity_types = [];
$entity_type_definations = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getDefinitions();
/* @var $definition EntityTypeInterface */
foreach ($entity_type_definations as $definition) {
  if ($definition instanceof ContentEntityType) {
    $content_entity_types[] = $definition;
  }
}
```

But a better approach would be to get the field first and then the bundles which has this field. For example, we are looking for the "field_image" in "node" typed entities:

```
   use Drupal\field\FieldStorageConfig;

   $field_image = FieldStorageConfig::load('node.field_image') 
   $bundles = $field_image->getBundles();
```

Comment: the id is just that, the id. $field_image = FieldStorageConfig::load('node.field_image') or the helper loadByName('node', 'field_image') are much easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

Builds a list of entity type labels suitable for a Form API options list

```
\Drupal::entityManager()->getEntityTypeLabels(TRUE);
```

Use in form API

```
$element['target_type'] = [
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('Type of item to reference'),
  '#options' => \Drupal::entityManager()->getEntityTypeLabels(TRUE),
  '#default_value' => '',
  '#required' => TRUE,
];
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It may help to provide a non-deprecated answer, which is to use the EntityRepositoryInterface rather than the EntityManagerInterface method.

Answer (score 1):

```
\Drupal::service('entity_type.repository')->getEntityTypeLabels(TRUE)['Content'];
```